# Android: get all installed packages using ADB

Tags: android, adb

How I can get the list of all installed on my Android 8 packages using ADB Shell?
I preference to query Sqlite base, but accept any command-line solution.

Answer (score 98):

```
adb shell cmd package list packages
```

This will return a list of the package names of the apps installed on the device. Each line is prefixed by `package:`.

There are even some options you can use:

```
list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-3] [-i] [-l] [-u] [-U] [--uid UID] [--user USER_ID] [FILTER]

Prints all packages; optionally only those whose name contains
the text in FILTER.
Options:
  -f: see their associated file
  -d: filter to only show disabled packages
  -e: filter to only show enabled packages
  -s: filter to only show system packages
  -3: filter to only show third party packages
  -i: see the installer for the packages
  -l: ignored (used for compatibility with older releases)
  -U: also show the package UID
  -u: also include uninstalled packages
  --uid UID: filter to only show packages with the given UID
  --user USER_ID: only list packages belonging to the given user
```

An alternative for older Android versions is

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

but this is deprecated and will likely be removed in the future.

Comment: `cmd` is not available on old Android versions. There, `pm` was the official way to list packages.

Comment: @tanius I already mention that.

Comment: WHAT ON EARTH do you mean by "other Android versions"??? That is so vague! Why not write OLDER or NEWER OS's of 9+ or 7+ or....?

Answer (score 62):

Get all installed packages using:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

To see user installed packages:

```
adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -f 2 -d ":"
```

Comment: The second command also removes `package:` from each listed package.