# How do i reinstall an Android app that is on Internal Test Track?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I developing a small Android app which I installed on my phone. Then I removed it. Now I want to reinstall it to check one thing I forgot.

When I use the Internel Test Track link to Google Play it says that the app is already installed.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed it.

- are you sure you are looking at the right package
- are you sure you are logged in as the same user who originally installed it in the Play store?

You can [check the apps installed on your phone from the command line using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634246/android-get-all-installed-packages-using-adb).

Try listing them all using adb to double check the package name for your app definitely isn't there.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but I'm quite sure it was installed in my usual account since I had trouble with it. And on Google Play on the web I'm logged in to my usual account. Can I still be mistaken?

Comment: Google Play on the web can be out of date, if it hasn't synced with the current status on your device. What does Google Play on the device say?

Comment: Google play on my phone does not find the app in Installed, Library or Beta.

Comment: And what happens when you try to install it from your phone?

Comment: Thanks. Opening the URL on my phone made it possible to install the app again. (It seems like they do not keep track of the states for apps on Internal Test Track.)

Comment: Hm, where did they hide the issue tracker?